# How to create a 'new entity' form as block in or under an entity (using Eck entities)

Tags: 7, forms, blocks, entities

There is this module '[Form block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock)' that creates blocks of node add/edit forms.
However, that module is not compatible with ECK entities (or custom entities in general)

What would be a good approach to create a similar solution for ECK entities?

Comment: I'd look into [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form)

Comment: @Felix -  thats an entity reference field widget, but I need something for the front end visitors.